# How do I set the target property on a label?

Tags: wpf

The following code:

```
    <TextBlock Name="foo"></TextBlock>
    <Label Target="foo">_Delta pressure</Label>
```

Generates the following design time error:

Error   1   Value 'foo' cannot be assigned to property 'Target'. Property 'Target' of type 'UIElement' cannot be specified as a string. C:\Programming\WpfCustomPlot\SPT.Olga.Plot.Custom\PumpCurves\View\RatedValuesView.xaml  65  45  SPT.Olga.Plot.Custom

And the following runtime error:

'UIElement' type does not have a public TypeConverter class.  Error at Line 65 Position 45.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `Target` property takes the element itself, not a string, so you want:

```
<TextBlock Name="foo"></TextBlock>
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=foo}">_Delta pressure</Label>
```

Comment: What if all these controls are in a DataTemplate (e.g. within ItemsControl)?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that in version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, this property was changed so that it would be able to just take the name of the element as a string. This was accomplished by decorating the `Label.Target` property with a `TypeConverterAttribute` using a `NameReferenceConverter` to handle the conversion from `String` to `UIElement`.

Check out the following docs for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.target(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.namereferenceconverter(v=vs.100).aspx

PS: Note that it is generally recognized as better practice to use the `x:Name` attribute to specify element names in XAML rather than the `Name` attribute.

Comment: Seems to work, but gives a Warning in the XAML editor

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @RomanoZumbé What's the warning that it's giving you? And I'm assuming that you're targeting .NET 4 or higher.

Comment: It says "The value must not be NULL. Parametername: context" (translated from german). I'm targeting .Net 4.5

Comment: @RomanoZumbé That's the error that it gives you when setting the Target property of a WPF Label in XAML? That doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: Interesting. After doing a search through the documents linked above, I found that the `NameReferenceConverter` uses services from a service provider to resolve the name, and it references that provider (of type `ITypeDescriptorContext`) as "context". The service provider is internal and supposed to be provided by the XAML processor in the XAML editor. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/service-contexts-available-to-type-converters-and-markup-extensions

Comment: As for why it isn't working correctly in your case, I have no idea. I would try  changing your `Target` to "{Binding ElementName=lstDirectories}" and see if you get the same error. If not, try to run your project and make sure it works correctly with your access key and everything. And then try to change it back to "lstDirectories" and see if you still get the error. If so, I would just give up on it and use the Binding syntax. LOL Good luck! ;)

Comment: I've already did all that and there is no warning with the binding syntax. But with the converter syntax I get the warning whatever I do. I think it's more of an academical problem. I'll just use the binding syntax. But always fun to try and find out whats wrong ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious why it isn't working too. But there's a point where the fun fades and you just have to go with what works. LOL Let me know if you ever find the answer and I hope you fare well in your endeavors. ;-)